# Django Application not getting registered in admin site

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created new application in Django project but it is not showing in admin page .
I have updated the admin.py file as well

I am looking for solution to get my app registered in admin page .
I have tried everything I could find in google .

admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import *
admin.site.register(packagedrop)
```

Modle

```
class packagedrop(models.Model):
    pkgID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    envname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    CreatedDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    prodhier = models.CharField( max_length=25)
    prodversion = models.CharField( max_length=40)
    initiator = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Submitted' )
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Have you added the app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? Are you logged in as a superuser?

Comment: yes app is added in Installed_apps .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your admin.py file.
It is recommended to import specific models by their names when importing the models from models.py.

Changing how you imported your model to `from .models import packagedrop` might solve the issue.

Also, before you do any of this, see if you haven't migrated your database.

The commands, in case you don't know

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`